# Replace string by an image

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use emoticons for my chat application. I am comparing the string I get or I send with a local string. If I am get the result as true I want to replace the string with an image. For that matter I am not using may emoticons.

I am trying this:

```
NSRange textRange;
textRange =[text rangeOfString:@":)"];

            if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {

                //Does contain the substring
            }
            else
            {

           // replace string with image.
            }
```

But I am not able to figure out how to replace image at the string position.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the string with an image"? Replace it where? Obviously, you cannot add images into `NSString` objects.

Comment: Replace the image at the position where text was there. eg I have a text "I am happy :)". I want :) to be replaced by smiley image.

Comment: I am getting text from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you want to put smileys.

So you can try this :

```
NSRange range = {NSNotFound, 0};
NSString *s = @"This is a smiley :) face";

range.location = 0;
range.length = [s length];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)"
                                    withString:@"\ue415"
                                       options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                         range:range];
```

For more detail please refer this [link](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-put-smiley-into-your-uilabel.html).

Comment: But how do I get codes for smileys. eg \ue415 for :). I want codes for other smileys also. How to get them?

Comment: I found [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-custom-chat-view-and-emoticons/) solved all my problem. I wanted to use basic emoticons only.